# Starting activity inside fragment boundaries itself

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to start a new activity inside the fragment boundaries itself instead of loading it in a complete new full screen.

I tried this :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Intent intent = new Intent(this,MenuFragmentActivity.class);
MenuFragment newFragment = new MenuFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.menuFragment,newFragment);
newFragment.startActivity(intent);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But this starts the activity in a new screen rather than in the confined fragment ?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is correct.

For layout purposes, activities cannot be "children" of fragments. It's the other way around: fragments are children of activities. So, basically, what you're trying to do won't work.

You should read the full [Fragments guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) if you haven't already. Here's the relevant quote about layouts:

> When you add a fragment as a part of your activity layout, it lives in
>   a ViewGroup inside the activity's view hierarchy and the fragment
>   defines its own view layout. You can insert a fragment into your
>   activity layout by declaring the fragment in the activity's layout
>   file, as a `<fragment>` element, or from your application code by adding
>   it to an existing ViewGroup.

Instead of starting a new activity, try just loading another fragment within the original fragment's layout.